# How to send veriables using redirect and use in other views

Tags: django, redirect

Im working on project and im sending data/veriable while redirecting flow from one view to another(first view/empty view)

```
def index(request,a=False):
    if request.method=='POST':
        return render(request,'chart-chart-js.html',{'a':True})
    return render(request,'chart-chart-js.html',{'a':a})

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.cleaned_data['username']=='Unknown' and form.cleaned_data['password']=='Unknown':
                
                return redirect(index,a=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass context variables using Redirect this way.

I can suggest two options:

1. Send and receive as a GET request parameter

In login function:

```
    return redirect(reverse(index) + '?a=VALUE')
```

In index function:

```
    a = request.GET.get('a')
```

2. Use Django Session

In login function:

```
    request.session['a'] = VALUE
    return redirect(index)
```

In index function:

```
    a = request.session.get('a')
```